# Two Django projects running simultaneously and mod_wsgi acting werid

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run two Django projects simultaneously. I happened to be using mod_wsgi, and found the site is acting weird. Perhaps there would be a workaround, but I'd like to know what I'm missing and how to solve the problem.

In the apache configuration

```
# Setup the Python environment
# As root owns basically everything on a Amazon AMI and root
# cannot be used. Create a folder under /var/run/wsgi
# with the owner as ec2-user and group ec2-user.
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
# Call your daemon process a name
WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon processes=1 threads=5
# Call your daemon process group a name
WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon
# Point to where the handler file is. This will be different
# If you are using some other framework.
WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/html/test/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /proto /var/www/html/proto/wsgi.py
```

After Apache restarts, if I connect to '/proto', then the proto site is shown. However, then I connect to '/test', without restarting Apache, the proto site is still shown, and I cannot access to the test site.

Now I restart Apache, this time I go to '/test' first. The test site comes up! However, if I go to '/proto' it still shows the test site, not the proto site.

What could make this happen? I added SESSION_COOKIE_PATH differently for each application just in case, but the problem still exists.

---

[UPDATED]

I also tried as the following, to give different WSGI application group names, but without luck.

```
Alias /cuedit /var/local/test/wsgi.py
<Location /test>
SetHandler wsgi-script
Options +ExecCGI
WSGIApplicationGroup test
</Location>
Alias /proto /var/local/proto/wsgi.py
<Location /proto>
SetHandler wsgi-script
Options +ExecCGI
WSGIApplicationGroup proto
</Location>
```

---

[UPDATED]

I changed from the daemon mode to the embedded mode. I guess the problem was two instances shared the same mod_wsgi daemon process so their namespace collide.

I would expect they should be handled correctly, but in the daemon mode I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Please don't put your code under `/var/www/html`.

Comment: And in each case I found no errors in the Apache error log, while the access log shows HTTP GET on each directory correctly

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you mean to put outside HTML directories?

Comment: Yes. It's code, not HTML. You don't want to risk it being served up as is. Put it outside the webroot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this as a workaround:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon-1 processes=1 threads=5
WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon-2 processes=1 threads=5

WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/html/test/wsgi.py

<Location /test>
WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon-1
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>

WSGIScriptAlias /proto /var/www/html/proto/wsgi.py

<Location /proto>
WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon-2
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>
```

This will force each application into separate daemon process group and no way they should be able to interfere with each other.

If that still doesn't work, you have problems with your WSGI script file somehow.

Comment: Exactly what I hoped I could do. Thank you so much!

Comment: It is a workaround though. What you had should work unless WSGIApplicationGroup was being overridden in a way to force use of single interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

I also have 2 Django projects however each one is running on a different port (httpd config), it looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xx
    ServerName xx
    ServerAlias xx
    ErrorLog /path/to/first/project/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/first/project/logs/access.log combined

    Alias /static/ /path/to/first/project/sitestatic

    WSGIDaemonProcess app processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup app

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/first/project/django.wsgi

    <Directory /path/to/first/project/apache>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin xx
    ServerName xx
    ServerAlias xx
    ErrorLog /path/to/second/project/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /path/to/second/project/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess app1 processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup app1

    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/second/project/apache/django.wsgi

     <Directory /path/to/second/project/apache>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any idea why the problem happens if I don't use virtual hosts?

Comment: This is an underrated answer. It worked PERFECTLY for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to Apache sharing the Python sub interpreter between WSGI applications. Try adding this to the Apache configuration to avoid sharing:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Check [this blog post](http://mediacore.com/blog/hosting-multiple-wsgi-applications-with-apache/) for in-depth explanation and additional tips (check the comments too).

Comment: You definitely don't want this. This will force them to run in the same, not separate. The default should be 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{RESOURCE}' which keeps them separate. The blog post suggests this to solve a different sort of problem.

Comment: I guess @Lycha 's solution could be related too, because although %{GLOBAL} forces them to run in the same, it prohibits using sub interpreter, and if the problem was in the sub interpreter, it might have solved the problem. Unfortunately, %{GLOBAL} didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Neither %{GLOBAL} nor %{RESOURCE} (default) solved the problem, but thank you both for the comments! You helped me learn a bit more about mod_wsgi.

Comment: btw, I never expected to have a comment from Graham Dumpleton!

Comment: I would have responded in detail, but overseas going to PyCon and bit busy. Solving technical problems like this is hard on SO. I'll give a workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the answer given by Graham, so adding one of my own.

The problem for me really was the Python Interpreter, but I also had to add the python-path for each interpreter. Here follows an example configuration:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess py_app1 processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/path/to/app1
WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /path/to/app1/wsgi.py
<Directory /path/to/app1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Location /app1>
    WSGIProcessGroup py_app1
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess py_app2 processes=1 threads=5 python-path=/path/to/app2
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /path/to/app2/wsgi.py
<Directory /path/to/app2>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
<Location /app2>
    WSGIProcessGroup py_app2
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Location>
```