# Hosting Multiple Django sites with mod_wsgi express / Apache

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, apache2.2

I am using mod_wsgi express in a virtualenv with Apache 2.2 and I want to serve multiple Django sites from the same server.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596969/2136394) mentions an approach I would like to use, but the `httpd.conf` generated for mod_wsgi express doesn't have `WSGIScriptAlias`, but instead uses `WSGIHandlerScript`

To generate my `httpd.conf` I ran this command:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --port=80 \
    --user apache --group apache \
    --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80 \
    --server-name=eco_test
```

which results in this being added at the end of the `httpd` script:

```
<IfDefine !ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIHandlerScript wsgi-handler '/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80-test1/handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='localhost:80' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIImportScript '/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80-test1/handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='localhost:80' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</IfDefine>

<IfDefine ONE_PROCESS>
WSGIHandlerScript wsgi-handler '/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80-test1/handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
WSGIImportScript '/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80-test1/handler.wsgi' \
    process-group='%{GLOBAL}' application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</IfDefine>
```

How would I set up aliases for more than one site when using `WSGIHandlerScript` and `WSGIImportScript`?  I am after `/eco` routes to `django_eco.wsgi` and `/pop` routes to `django_pop.wsgi`

I am willing to have each Django site run their own port (e.g. 8080, 8081, etc...) if that is necessary.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553165/multiple-django-sites-with-apache-mod-wsgi

Comment: I had seen that.  My question is more regarding me not understanding what parts of the `httpd.conf` file auto-generated by mod_wsgi express should be altered in conjunction with `WSGIHandlerScript` & `WSGIImportScript`.

Comment: I ended up using NGINX as a reverse proxy for my Django sites, each running locally on their own ports.