# Django VirtualHosting: How to host multiple django projects with different domains on one VPS

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost, vps

Because I've heard you can host multiple websites on one VPS so I was trying to implement it, with django ( not installed in VEnvironment ), and using mod_wsgi with apache.

When I first got this VPS I was really getting started with the django, and following some tutorials from django official site, I got it to work now the problems are as follows -

**1. Different Tutorials assuming different directory structures for apache**
the structure I got after installing apache on my Ubuntu server that I bought from digiocean with one click django setup, is like this.

## /etc/apache2/

```
   |-- apache2.conf
   |       `--  ports.conf
   |-- mods-enabled
   |       |-- *.load
   |       `-- *.conf
   |-- conf-enabled
   |       `-- *.conf
   `-- sites-enabled
           `-- *.conf
```

following the tutorial ( official ) I got my first project ( site1 ) to work.
Now I have this new site and that is also based on django. So I thought maybe there could be a decent way of hosting both of them under one hood.

**2. many .conf files in apache**

I know this might sound like a lame question but as I was reading django on apache with mod_wsgi I found instructions telling that I have to do changes in the ***httpd.conf*** file left me wondering why are there any vhost files in the sites-available folder.

**3. Difference between hosting two sites say (.php ) based and django**

I read there are a lot of reference about the **DocumentRoot** configuration under the VirtualHost configuration, while I have all my document under

`/home/django/`

if there is a difference between hosting two sites other than django than maybe someone would be kind enough to answer.

### Now Coming to the point

a. should I move my project folder to /var/www/ if so why and will symlinks do the trick

b. as the django tutorial suggested I should configure WSGISCriptAlias and other settings in httpd.conf, Should I go with this or what should I do, this Is really important for me to understand maybe someone could point me in the direction where I could learn about it.

c. I have one systemwide installation of django does that effect in virtual hosting.

d. should I use different ports to run different websites and if yes how would I configure that.

e. Suggest me an approach that is tested with apache and mod_wsgi ( please )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to be as laconic as possible.

1. You really need to read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/#how-to-deploy-with-wsgi) (and even [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/getting-started.html)) and the more you read the better it'll be, since you won't get here an explicit answer on how to serve django-sites on apache with details and examples.
2. There your project live is up to you, in other words it should not be necessarily placed to `/var/www/`
3. In order to hold 2+ django projects at once try to use separate wsgi daemon processes. Have a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596969/5253807). This will not allow different applications to interfere with each other. And yet, I would recommend to set configs for your  projects (as vhosts) in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` files (one per file, typically).
4. I would strongly recommend you not to work with globally installed django, but to have a separate for each project (using venv or in some other way depends to you). This way you'll make the process of upgrading packages and django much more secure.

Comment: I got it to work by merely changing few lines. I added ServerAlias in both virtual host blocks and it worked.